# Jquery loop through items from .get and use jquery to get .text()

Tags: jquery

I'm grabbing list elements using `.get()` and putting them into an object.  Now in the $.each() I'd like to loop through each item and be able to use things like `.text()` to extract text or `.attr('href')`, etc.  I've tried things like value.text(), etc but I can't seem to get it to work. Do I need to do something else to achieve this? Thank you if this is an obvious answer I'm missing.

```
//Gets all list elements from parent menu
var items = $(this).closest('.menu-column').find('li').get();

//Loop through each list element and log the text
$.each(items, function(key, value){
   console.log('hit it');
   console.log(value.text());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('.menu-column li').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();
    console.log(value);
});
```

Inside the each() function you can use $(this) to access the list item jQuery functions like addClass(), html(), text(), etc...